# Touch Input in Kivy

Tags: kivy, touch-event

I have a simple app with 2 buttons and their attached callback functions. When a button is pressed, I need to get and use the spos info. I'm using the following code

Python:

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):

    print('Start')
    port = "COM7"
    bluetooth = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
    print("Connected to HC-06")

    def button_press_down(self, *args):
        print("button pressed @location:")
        self.bluetooth.write(b"2")


    def button_press_up(self, *args):
        print("button pressed @location:")
        self.bluetooth.write(b"3")

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        pass



class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv=Builder.load_file('touch.kv')

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp = MainApp()
    TestApp.run()
```

.kv file:

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
WindowManager:
    HomeScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<HomeScreen>:
    name: "button press"
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        GridLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            rows: 1
            cols: 2
            padding:10

            Button:
                text: "Button_1"
                id:send_data_bluettooh

                on_press:
                    root.button_press_down()

            Button:
                text: "Button_2"
                id:send_data_bluettooh_2

                on_press:
                    root.button_press_up()

<SecondScreen>:
    name: "SecondScreen"
```

I can get the spos by overwriting the "on_touch_down" fct. The problem there is that my fct button_press_down() is no longer called when I press button 1. Is there any way I can use the spos info and still keep the callback function button_press_down() of my button?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `touch.spos` by extending the `Button` class so that it remembers that information. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class MyButt(Button):
    last_touch_down = ListProperty([])
    last_touch_up = ListProperty([])

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.last_touch_down = touch.spos
        return super(MyButt, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.last_touch_up = touch.spos
        return super(MyButt, self).on_touch_up(touch)


class HomeScreen(Screen):

    print('Start')
    port = "COM7"
    bluetooth = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
    print("Connected to HC-06")

    def button_press_down(self, button):
        print("button pressed @location:", button.last_touch_down)
        self.bluetooth.write(b"2")


    def button_press_up(self, button):
        print("button pressed @location:", button.last_touch_down)
        self.bluetooth.write(b"3")

    # def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    #     print(touch)
    #     return super(HomeScreen, self).on_touch_down(touch)
    #
    # def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    #     pass



class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv=Builder.load_file('touch.kv')

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp = MainApp()
    TestApp.run()
```

And replacing `Button` with `MyButt` in the `kv`:

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
WindowManager:
    HomeScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<HomeScreen>:
    name: "button press"
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        GridLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            rows: 1
            cols: 2
            padding:10

            MyButt:
                text: "Button_1"
                id:send_data_bluettooh

                on_press:
                    root.button_press_down(self)

            MyButt:
                text: "Button_2"
                id:send_data_bluettooh_2

                on_press:
                    root.button_press_up(self)

<SecondScreen>:
    name: "SecondScreen"
```